# Property of $(p-3)! + 1$, where $p$ is a prime.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am currently working on a take home exam for undergraduate number theory so I can only accept hints. The problem I am working on is: Let $p$ be an odd prime such that $p \equiv 3,5$ mod $8$. Prove that $(p-3)! + 1$ is not a perfect square. My approach so far is:

If $(p-3)! + 1$ is a perfect square, then it would a perfect square mod $p$. By Wilson's theorem, $(p-3)! + 1 \equiv (-1)(p-1)^{-1}(p-2)^{-1} + 1 \text{ mod } p$. Since $(p-1)^{-1} \equiv_{p} (p-1)$ and $(-1) \equiv_{p} (p-1)$, we have $(-1)(p-1)^{-1}(p-2)^{-1} + 1 \equiv ((p-2)^{-1} + 1) \text{ mod } p$. We know $(p-2)^{-1} \equiv_{p} (-2)^{-1} = \frac{p-1}{2}$ so, $((p-2)^{-1} + 1) \equiv_{p} \frac{p-1}{2} + 1 = \frac{p+1}{2}.$

At this point, I am quite stuck and would appreciate any feed back or hints as to another approach I can use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hints:

- You are on a good path with having shown that $2((p-3)!+1)\equiv1$.
- Recall when $2$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$ and when it is not.